# How to get nvidia driver installed on 13.10

Tags: nvidia, 13.10

I found severel links , butnothing works.
I tried system configuration to install over frontend
I always end up in a black screen

NOTHING Works

Please give advise

Peter Schlaeger

Answer (score 2):

Install throught "Additional drivers" or try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

If it won't work, enter virtual console `CTRL + ALT + F1` give login and password when asked, go to location where you downloaded latest NVidia drivers and:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo chmod a+x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.20.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.20.run
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Run this lines in a terminal, one after another:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings-331
```

And then, reboot and you're good to go, with the official latest drivers. Other solutions to install from binaries from nvidia site have caused me a lot of troubles before, this is the best solution I've found and I've been using it the last four releases.

Comment: This is what I did and I end up in a black screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to install the drivers for your nvidia graphics card. it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

this will install the nvidia-settings too.